# Bootstrap Glyphicons change font family on button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have been using Bootstraps Glyphicons for a couple of days and I tried to add some text inside a button with glyphicon icon:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr:{'href':'#'+'TableA'}">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="text:' Details'"></span>
 </button>
```

Which it shows me a table when clicked. I need the text to be Arial but if I change it inside `bootstrap.css` or I add:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="text:' Download', style:{fontFamily: 'Arial'}"></span>
```

It changes the text font-family into Arial but the glyphicon icons disappear.
What am I doing wrong? It is possible to change the font-family of a text inside a button with glyphicon icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put the text you want to change the font of inside a span within the element. Then assign a class or id to the span and in the css file change the font-family of the span to the one you need, that shouldn't effect the Glyph.

/S

Comment: Thanks @ste3333. You were the first to give me the idea so I'll mark your answer as the one who resolved my problem. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 4):

The font was fixed after I expanded the short `<span/>` definition to the expended one (`<span></span>`).

Original version (invalid font):

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"/>
            &nbsp;Send message
        </button>
```

Fixed version:

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
            &nbsp;Send message
        </button>
```

I don't really understand why this worked for me...

Comment: you saved my day, mate! Thank you

Comment: The glyphicon class is essentially a font (a bit like the old wingdings font, except wingding's completely replaced the letters), and so applies it's own font settings. When the </span> is closed those settings (i.e. the glyphicon font) are no longer applied, reverting to the font being applied by next enclosing element. FYI, because of this yours is the best answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use something as

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr:{'href':'#'+'TableA'}">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
     <span style="--your style--">Download</span>
 </button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Kumar. Your answer was the same as the previous one, but yours in code. I can't mark two answers so I'll mark the other because it was the first who answered my question. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Not a issue , discussion is the key to learn .. happy coding :)